# Different meditation approaches within Theravada

Tags: theravada, vipassana, jhana, insight, mahasi

I talked to a monk at a Thai Theravada based monastery recently and he told me that they primarily use breath meditation and jhana to gain awakening.  And then there are other traditions, like yours, that emphasis vipassana to gain awakening.  To me, they seem like completely different paths.  Do you know why it is that different monasteries within the same regional tradition of Theravada have completely different approaches?  Are they equally useful in gaining awakening?

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are 4 ways and they are all valid Theravada techniques. Problem occurs when misinformed people start saying only one of these techniques is correct.

1. Insight preceded by tranquility
2. Tranquility preceded by insight
3. Tranquility in tandem with insight
4. by settling the mind with regard to the Dhamma.

Read the [Yuganandha Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.170.than.html) for more details